# How to check the number of open browser windows using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I have an open browser window where the user clicks a button and after that, a new browser window opens with a new page.
How can I check that there are two browser windows open and not two pages?
The browser.browserContexts() property does not work, because if a new browser window is opened after clicking on another browser window, then these two browser windows have the same context.